# What does 入れてください mean in 毎日、時間があろうとなかろうと、連絡だけは**入れてください**。?

Tags: meaning

What does 入れてください mean in

> 毎日、時間があろうとなかろうと、連絡だけは**入れてください**。?

Word definitions according to Jisho.org: [入れてください](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%85%A5%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84)

> 1. to put in; to let in; to take in; to bring in; to insert; to install (e.g. software); to set (a jewel, etc.); to ink in (e.g. tattoo)
> 2. to admit; to accept; to employ; to hire​
> 3. to accept; to comply; to grant; to adopt (a policy, etc.); to take (advice, etc.); to listen to; to pay attention to esp. 容れる
> 4. to include​
> 5. to pay (one's rent, etc.)​
> 6. to cast (a vote)​
> 7. to make (tea, coffee, etc.)​
> 8. to turn on (a switch, etc.)​
> 9. to send (a fax); to call​

I'm hesitant to choose a definition that fits the sentence above.

Answer (score 2):

連絡を入れる is same as 連絡を取る.
It means simply "to get in touch with someone".

In this sentence, だけは emphasizes instructions.

So 連絡だけは入れてください
means that "be sure that you get in touch with me/them".

Answer (score 2):

[デジタル大辞林](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%84%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B/#jn-15682) says:

> いれる
> 10 相手に連絡する。「電話をいれる」「第一報をいれる」

連絡を入れる means "to contact someone (usually via phone)".

So I think the closest definition in jisho.org would be...

> 9. to send (a fax); to call

... perhaps?